# Why is this locking up? Loop through all rows, perform function on duplicate, delete duplicate row

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, duplicates

The code works when I bite off a couple hundred rows at a time, but always hangs somewhere in the middle when I try to run it on 10,000.

**What the code does:** Looks for duplicate entries in column A, adds the values in columns c, d and e between the two rows, then deletes the original row.

Can anybody think of a more stable way to do this, or point me towards why it might be locking up?

```
Sub combineDelete ()
  Const TEST_COLUMN As String = "A"
  Dim i As Long
  Dim iLastRow As Long
  With ActiveSheet
  iLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, TEST_COLUMN).End(xlUp).Row
  For i = iLastRow To 2 Step -1
  If Cells(i, 1) = Cells(i - 1, 1) Then
    s = Cells(i, 3).Value
    t = Cells(i - 1, 3).Value
    Cells(i - 1, 3) = s + t
    u = Cells(i, 4).Value
    v = Cells(i - 1, 4).Value
    Cells(i - 1, 4) = u + v
    w = Cells(i, 5).Value
    y = Cells(i - 1, 5).Value
    Cells(i - 1, 5) = w + y
    Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete
  End If
  Next i
End With
End Sub
```

[Edit: Here's a link to a sample subset of the data.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/y6jmxib68irfx9p/sampleExcel-ja.xlsx?dl=0)

Post-edit: Every one of these ideas is effective. Ron Rosenberg's solution below manages to handle it orders of magnitude faster than any solution I tinkered with. Thanks!

Comment: I'm assuming I could make the code better by optimizing my kludgy stuff inside the loop — would that make it more stable?

Comment: Try disabling screen updating ( `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` )

Comment: @jawtry How do you know that it is "hanging in the middle"?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld — I let it sit for 10 minutes or so and then abort. If I scroll through the rows, I can see that it's working its way up, and hangs at a random interval a thousand in or so. Additionally, if I perform it on a smaller dataset (1k rows or so), it works fine.

Comment: @jawtry Do you have the Options set to break on errors?  Can you supply a small, sample database?  Is column A sorted, and, if not, do you want to combine duplicates that are not adjacent?

Comment: @NickSlash — That definitely helped! Still took several nail-biting minutes, but it didn't hang this time! Thinking:

Comment: In doing some experimenting, it looks like the time-consuming part is row deletion. Wondering if there's a trick to do everything above EXCEPT the EntireRow.Delete. Then using autofilter to hide the duplicates based on column A? I'd have to figure out how to hide the ones that weren't the keeper that we added things into. 

I'll think, and answer Ron's question above.

Comment: @jawtry There is a much faster method, but please answer my questions.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld — Added a link to a subset of the data in the main post above. I don't have the options set to break on errors.

Comment: On the sorting, I have the data pre-sorted, first by Column A, then by Column B, so any duplicates are already adjacent.

Comment: @jawtry -- your code is ignoring column B.  How do you want to handle that?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld — It's supposed to take the highest value from column B (the lower value will be deleted). With the pre-sort on it (Column A, A-Z and Column B high to low), it should take care of itself without additional VBA.

Comment: @jawtry Are there only the five columns?  Or could there be more?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld — Just the five. You're seeing the whole width of the data — just add 10k rows, and you're there. . . .

Comment: You could try working with arrays instead of the actual cells, this wouldn't take more than a second even for 100K rows, it will require a little extra coding though if your up for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a routine that should run quite rapidly.  You will note near the top of the code where to change the source and results worksheets if you want.

The work is done within VBA arrays, which will be much faster than working on the worksheet.

I create a User defined object whose properties are the contents of the TestColumn; the Maximum amount in  Column B; and an array of the Sum of Columns C, D and E.

These are placed into a Collection object with the Key being the TestColumn.  If there is a duplicate, the Collection object will return a 457 error, which we test for and use to combine the rows.

Finally, we write the collection object back to an array, and write that array to the worksheet.

You will use both a **Class Module** and a **Regular Module**

The original data does not need to be sorted, but you can if you want, either before or after running this macro.

Enjoy.

### Class Module

Be sure to rename this module **cCombo** after inserting it

```
Rename this module **cCombo**
Option Explicit
Private pTestColumn As String
Private pMaxColumn As Double
Private pSumColumns(3 To 5) As Variant

Public Property Get TestColumn() As String
    TestColumn = pTestColumn
End Property
Public Property Let TestColumn(Value As String)
    pTestColumn = Value
End Property

Public Property Get MaxColumn() As Double
    MaxColumn = pMaxColumn
End Property
Public Property Let MaxColumn(Value As Double)
    pMaxColumn = IIf(pMaxColumn > Value, pMaxColumn, Value)
End Property

Public Property Get SumColumns() As Variant
    SumColumns = pSumColumns
End Property
Public Property Let SumColumns(Value As Variant)
    Dim I As Long
    For I = LBound(Value) To UBound(Value)
        pSumColumns(I) = pSumColumns(I) + Value(I)
    Next I
End Property
```

### Regular Module

```
Option Explicit

Sub combineDelete()
  Const TEST_COLUMN As String = "A"
  Dim vSrc As Variant, vRes As Variant, rRes As Range
  Dim wsSrc As Worksheet, wsRes As Worksheet
  Dim cC As cCombo, colC As Collection
  Dim I As Long, J As Long, V As Variant, S As String

Set wsSrc = Worksheets("sheet1")
Set wsRes = Worksheets("sheet2") 'could be same sheet if you want to overwrite
    Set rRes = wsRes.Cells(2, 1)

'Get original data
With wsSrc
    vSrc = Range(.Cells(2, TEST_COLUMN), .Cells(.Rows.Count, TEST_COLUMN).End(xlUp)).Resize(columnsize:=5)
End With
ReDim V(3 To UBound(vSrc, 2)) 'for storing rows

'Collect the data, eliminating duplicates
Set colC = New Collection
On Error Resume Next
For I = 1 To UBound(vSrc, 1)
    Set cC = New cCombo
    With cC
        .TestColumn = vSrc(I, 1)
        .MaxColumn = vSrc(I, 2)
        For J = 3 To UBound(vSrc, 2)
            V(J) = vSrc(I, J)
        Next J
        .SumColumns = V

        colC.Add Item:=cC, Key:=.TestColumn
        Select Case Err.Number
            Case 457
                Err.Clear
                colC(.TestColumn).MaxColumn = .MaxColumn
                colC(.TestColumn).SumColumns = .SumColumns
            Case Is <> 0
                Debug.Print Err.Number, Err.Description
                Stop
        End Select
    End With
Next I
On Error GoTo 0

'Create results array
ReDim vRes(1 To colC.Count, 1 To 5)
For I = 1 To colC.Count
    With colC(I)
        vRes(I, 1) = .TestColumn
        vRes(I, 2) = .MaxColumn
        V = .SumColumns
        For J = LBound(V) To UBound(V)
            vRes(I, J) = V(J)
        Next J
    End With
Next I

'Write the results
Set rRes = rRes.Resize(UBound(vRes, 1), UBound(vRes, 2))
With rRes
    .EntireColumn.Clear
    .Value = vRes
    .EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = 5
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: THIS IS AMAZING. I'll spend all week learning from it — it works in less than 2 seconds! One clarification: because of the named sheets (wsSrc being "sheet1"), it only works if the sheet is sheet1. Is it a coding no-no to just declare wsSrc as Activesheet? (It works — just not sure if it's 'proper.')

Comment: Just wow — thanks again for the major assist! The class module is new for me, but I'll spend some time reading up on it.

Comment: @jawtry It will work, **but** it is more robust to name specific sheets.  What happens if, sometime in the future, you add a specific sheet that you don't want to have processed, and someone accidentally runs the macro?  If you have a bunch of sheets, you can loop through them by name.

Comment: @jawtry see [Introduction to Classes](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/Classes.aspx) on Chip Pearson's excellent web site.  I found Classes often handy for keeping track of what I am trying to do, and being able to use meaningful names as properties.

Answer (score 1):

Start with this and let us know how things are going afterwards:

```
Option Explicit

Sub combineDelete()

Const TEST_COLUMN As String = "A"
Dim i As Long
Dim iLastRow As Long
Dim s As Double, t As Double, u As Double
Dim v As Double, w As Double, y As Double

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

With ActiveSheet
    iLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, TEST_COLUMN).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = iLastRow To 2 Step -1
        If .Cells(i, 1).Value2 = .Cells(i - 1, 1).Value2 Then
            s = .Cells(i, 3).Value2
            t = .Cells(i - 1, 3).Value2
            .Cells(i - 1, 3).Value2 = s + t
            u = .Cells(i, 4).Value2
            v = .Cells(i - 1, 4).Value2
            .Cells(i - 1, 4).Value2 = u + v
            w = .Cells(i, 5).Value2
            y = .Cells(i - 1, 5).Value2
            .Cells(i - 1, 5).Value2 = w + y
            .Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i
End With

With Application
    .EnableEvents = True
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

End Sub
```

Notes:

1. Disable screenupdating, calculations and events
2. Use `.Value2` instead of `.Value`
3. Explicit coding
4. Missing references to `ActiveSheet` added by adding dots `.`
5. Dim all variables to avoid variants

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! This is much more proper code. It takes almost as long to run (about 3-4 minutes), but doesn't appear to hang at all. It still feels like there should be a more efficient way to do this — but this version is stable. Hugely appreciated!

Comment: Just a query - why .value2 ?

Answer (score 0):

Working with ~10K rows would benefit immensely from a variant array but you can also make significant improvements by deleting all of the rows at once. While you could gather a [Union](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834621.aspx) of the rows to delete, a [Range.RemoveDuplicates method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193823.aspx) is also appropriate in this case.

It is unclear on whether your data is sorted on a primary key of column A. Your current code depends upon this but I've changed the criteria check to the [Excel Application object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194565.aspx)'s [MATCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) to accommodate unsorted data.

Your code appears to avoid text column header labels in row 1. I've used the [Range.CurrentRegion property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196678.aspx) to localize the cells to be processed.

```
Sub combineDelete()
    Const TEST_COLUMN As String = "A"
    Dim i As Long, mtch As Long

    'appTGGL bTGGL:=False 'uncomment this line once you have completed debugging

    With ActiveSheet
        With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
            For i = .Rows.Count To 2 Step -1
                mtch = Application.Match(.Cells(i, 1).Value, .Columns(1), 0)
                If mtch < i Then
                    .Cells(mtch, 3) = Application.Sum(.Cells(mtch, 3), .Cells(i, 3))
                    .Cells(mtch, 4) = Application.Sum(.Cells(mtch, 4), .Cells(i, 4))
                    .Cells(mtch, 5) = Application.Sum(.Cells(mtch, 5), .Cells(i, 5))
                End If
            Next i
            .RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes
        End With
    End With

    appTGGL

End Sub

Public Sub appTGGL(Optional bTGGL As Boolean = True)
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = bTGGL
        .EnableEvents = bTGGL
        .DisplayAlerts = bTGGL
        .Calculation = IIf(bTGGL, xlCalculationAutomatic, xlCalculationManual)
        .StatusBar = vbNullString
    End With
    Debug.Print Timer
End Sub
```

The use of `Application.Sum(..., ...)` is a trifle slower than straight addition but it has the benefit of providing error control over text values. This may or may not be a desired behavior; i.e. you might want to know when you are trying to add text to a number instead of skipping over it.

There were many places inside your [With ... End With statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx) where you used `Cells(i, 3)` and not `.Cells(i, 3)` (note the prefix `.` ). If you are going to take the time to reference the [Range.Parent property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa224980.aspx) (and you should always do so!) then it seems a shame not to use it.

I've included a reusable 'helper' sub that 'turns off' many application environment states but left it commented. Uncomment it once you havew completed debugging for additional speed and stability.

**[Addendum for lookup strings with length > 255](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251825.aspx)**

```
Sub combineDelete()
    Dim i As Long, mtch As Long
    Dim vCOLAs As Variant, dCOLAs As Object

    'appTGGL bTGGL:=False 'uncomment this line once you have completed debugging

    Set dCOLAs = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dCOLAs.CompareMode = vbTextCompare

    With ActiveSheet
        With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
            'strings in column A may exceed 255 chars; build array and and a dictionary from array
            vCOLAs = .Resize(.Rows.Count, 1).Value2
            For i = UBound(vCOLAs, 1) To LBound(vCOLAs, 1) Step -1
                'fast overwrite method
                dCOLAs.Item(vCOLAs(i, 1)) = i
            Next i
            For i = .Rows.Count To 2 Step -1
                mtch = dCOLAs.Item(vCOLAs(i, 1))
                If mtch < i Then
                    .Cells(mtch, 3) = Application.Sum(.Cells(mtch, 3), .Cells(i, 3))
                    .Cells(mtch, 4) = Application.Sum(.Cells(mtch, 4), .Cells(i, 4))
                    .Cells(mtch, 5) = Application.Sum(.Cells(mtch, 5), .Cells(i, 5))
                End If
            Next i
            .RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes
        End With
    End With

    Erase vCOLAs
    dCOLAs.RemoveAll: Set dCOLAs = Nothing

    appTGGL

End Sub
```

A dictionary object provides lightning fast lookups due to its unique keys. Since these are a variant type, there is no 255 character limit.

Comment: I love this solution (the 'union' and delete part has been beyond my skills). But I'm getting a 'type mismatch error 13' when I run it. The loop appears to function — the error is returned when I hit .RemoveDuplicates . . . Any advice?

Comment: You could try `Columns:=Array(1)` instead of `Columns:=1` . It shouldn't be necessary for a single column but that might throw the mismatch error. Could be a version specific issue as it doesn't throw an error on my xl2010 (with updated SPs). Tested on 15K rows with ~30% duplicates in column A.

Comment: After looking at the sample data you provided, I believe you are mistaken in the location of the error. The [MATCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) has a 255 character limit for its *lookup_value*. While your sample data does not exceed that, it certainly looks like there may be other data within the 10K rows that would. Any text in column A that was over the 255 character limit in length is going to throw a type 13: mismatch error.

Comment: Ah — THAT would likely explain it. So, theoretically, I could create a "new column A" that would just use "=left" for the first 250 characters, correct?

Comment: Let me see if I can get a variant array working correctly. You don't want to have to build a 'helper' column of 10K rows if you can avoid it.

Comment: Sure I'm missing something — but, towards the end of the run, I get a dialog box asking which duplicates to remove and a series of column check marks, saying 'no duplicates found.' What am I missing?

Comment: Perhaps you reran it on data that already had the duplicates removed.